# In Java, why does (unsorted) Set implement Iterable, but SortedMap does not?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

There are two aspects to this question that I felt were too closely related to ask as separate questions.

1. Why doesn't `SortedMap` implement `Iterable<Map.Entry<K,V>>`?

If you need to perform an action on every key-value pair in a map, iterating over the entrySet() seems like the way to go.  So why not provide a direct iterator() method on SortedMap?  Unless you are worried about iteration order being inconsistent in a HashMap.  Which leads me to:

2. Does implementing `Iterable` imply a stable ordering?

Iterating over an ordered collection (List, SortedMap, SortedSet) is a great way to reliably implement equals() (see Note 1) and do other things that have to produce the same result every time.  Iterating over an unsorted set or map could yield different ordering if you call it multiple times, so is unsuitable for these purposes.  Especially if you are comparing HashSets or HashMaps - two of them could contain the same objects, but the order of their iterators would be different.

I guess there are 2 aspects to those questions:

1. What are the historical reasons for these design decisions?
2. If doing it again today, are there correct answers to these questions?  Maybe `OrderedIterable` should extend `Iterable` to guarantee order?

**Notes:**

1. I had originally suggested that you needed a reliable ordering to implement hashCode(), but if you sum all the hashcodes, it turns out that you don't need a reliable ordering if your hashing algorithm is commutative.  Addition is commonly used for hashCodes and it is commutative: a + b = b + a and B. even with overflow, addition is still commutative so that a + Integer.MAX_VALUE = Integer.MAX_VALUE + a.  You do still need a reliable ordering to implement equals() so that you can compare the first item of one to the first item of the other, etc.

**P.S.**

This question is about the interfaces `Iterable`, `Set`, `SortedSet`, `Map`, and `SortedMap`.  It's fine to bring up other interfaces as examples, but
I do not think the `Collection` interface is relevant to this question.  It's quirky and has the potential to be a distraction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although it is correct from a narrowly technical point of view to say that `Set` implements `Iterable`, but `SortedMap` does not, it is not a very useful question to ask.  A more useful question to ask is whether both classes ***offer*** the `Iterable` interface, and they certainly both do.

As you know, there are three ways to offer an interface:

1. By explicitly implementing it using the `implements` keyword.
2. By implementing an interface which extends the interface in question.
3. By exposing a function which returns the interface in question.

`Set` is declared as follows: `public interface Set<E> extends Collection<E> {...` so, as you can see, `Set` does not directly implement `Iterable`, it only implements it indirectly, by virtue of implementing `Collection`, which extends `Iterable`.

Now, `SortedMap` *would* also be implementing `Iterable` indirectly, just as `Set` does, if it was implementing `Collection`, but it does not even do that.  Instead, it exposes an `entrySet()` function, which returns a `Collection`, which extends `Iterable`.

So, you can have your much desired `Iterable` in both cases.

If you would like to insist on the narrowly technical question of why `Set` (indirectly) implements `Iterable`, but `SortedMap` offers it via a function instead, the answer is that the designers of the java language runtime made the decision a long time ago to refrain from making extensive use of  interfaces extending other interfaces. That's why `Map<K,V>` does not extend `Collection<Map.Entry<K,V>>`, offering an `entrySet()` method instead.

They could have done the opposite, and as a matter of fact the designers of the C# language runtime did choose to go the other way, so `IDictionary<K,V>` extends `ICollection<KeyValuePair<K,V>>`.

I have experimented with both ways, and I still have not arrived at a conclusive decision as to which one is better.  They simply appear to be two different ways of accomplishing the same thing.

The implementation of `Iterator` does not imply a stable ordering, as you seem to understand (and therefore it is not clear to me where your question is in that respect.)  You may iterate over an unsorted map, in which case nobody can tell what the order of the items will be, and you may insert an element to the map and re-iterate, in which case the order of the items may be completely different from the previous time.  (Not just different by one item: all items may appear to be re-arranged.)

There is no need for an `OrderedIterable` interface because its signature would be identical to `Iterable`.  (And don't get me started on the choice of the java people to introduce a `Set` besides `Collection`.)  You can just invoke `OrderedMap.entrySet()`, which the documentation promises will return an *ordered* set, which means that the `Iterator` of that set will always yield items in order.

Comment: By implementing Iterator, you only guarantee that it has an end eventually.  You could in theory create a RandomCardIterator that gives you random cards until you've consumed all cards in a deck.    What he's probably thinking of is [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) which does guarantee a specific ordering.

Comment: @Neil I haven't seen anything in Iterator that implies that it ends as part of the contract, just that it will tell you when it ends if it does.  I've seen `class Primes implements Iterator<Long> { public boolean hasNext() { return true; } ... }`

Comment: @MichaelT Honestly, neither have I, though it'd only take a for(Element ele : elements) to create an infinite loop in that case.  I would say Streams are better suited for that sort of thing.

Comment: I understood that Set (implicitly) disallowed duplicates while Collection does allow it.

Comment: @Neil if the code ever goes through a process where Java 8 is acceptable then that would be a consideration. For a 1.6 world, this was a way of doing a lazy list of Primes.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I mentioned `Set` and `Collection` as an example of two interfaces which are identical in every respect except the comments.  I do not think `Set` was a very good idea on behalf of whoever came up with it.

Comment: Thank you.  You raise good points.  I've edited my question to put `Collection` out-of-bounds.  It forces List to implement contains() (will be O(n) slow) and Set to implement iterable() and toArray() (order can change).  It can only muddy the waters.

Comment: @GlenPeterson well, actually, you cannot just put `Collection` out of bounds to your question, because it just so happens that the answer to your question can only be obtained by considering the `Collection` interface.  I amended my answer to indicate how.